# Не работает justify-content. Все блоки слипаются

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Не очень понимаю, почему все слова все равно у меня слипаются, а свойство не работает.

```css
.header__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.69;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff
}

.items__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__row">
  <div class="header__img">
    <img src="img/logo/logo_43.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="header__items">
    <div class="items__row">
      <div class="items__features">Features</div>
      <div class="items__about">About</div>
      <div class="items__pricing">Pricing</div>
      <div class="items__reviews">Reviews</div>
      <div class="items__contact">Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что элементы заполняют всю ширину родительского контейнера. А так как у контейнера items__row не задана ширина, то элементы упаковываются в минимально возможную ширину и justify-content не влияет вообще ни на что

Comment: Вообще div'ы по умолчанию заполняют максимально возможную ширину, но так как у родительского контейнера header__items стоит display: flex и justify-content: space-between, то в итоге контейнер items__row стремится занять минимально возможную ширину

Comment: И как тогда это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Для отступа между `flex` блоками, можно использовать свойство [gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
Я вам прописал отступ в `20px`.

```css
gap: 20px;
```

```css
.header__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0.69;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 600;
  /*color: #ffffff*/
}

.items__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 45px;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__row">
  <div class="header__img">
    <img src="img/logo/logo_43.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="header__items">
    <div class="items__row">
      <div class="items__features">Features</div>
      <div class="items__about">About</div>
      <div class="items__pricing">Pricing</div>
      <div class="items__reviews">Reviews</div>
      <div class="items__contact">Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Не слышал о таком свойстве... Ну, я пока что еще гриды не изучал. Если это с гридами связано, конечно...

Comment: @nevverof: свойство _gap_ добавили для _flex_ относительно недавно, а у _grid_ оно было изначально.

Answer (score 0):

Смотри, justify-content создаёт расстояние между элементами внутри ( в твоём случае все что находится внутри items__row). Однако у items__row нету определённой ширины, она имеет по умолчанию width:auto, от чего имеет ширину равной сумме width всего что входит внутрь себя, расширяется и сжимается в зависимости от того что внутри(тебе это тоже понадобится знать в будущем, запомни эту инфу чтобы создавать адаптивные блоки). Тебе нужно дать items__row width или min-width, тогда justify-content сработает.

У тебя в комментариях к вопросу Андрей первый раз правильно говорит, а на втором комменте путается, ведь div,nav,sector и др не стараются заняться максимальную длину или высоту, если они пустые и родитель не даёт им высоты или ширины(например если бы были внутри grid и каждый элемент имел 1fr или больше ширину или высоту). Также он путается и header__items не имеет justify-content, даже имея его он бы не повлиял на содержимое items-row, только на него самого.

Ответ пилатона сработает, но код не чистый будет, создастся проблема в будущем при созданий адаптивности(придётся медиа запросы добавлять каждый раз), также добавив просто gap: , ты сделаешь отступы со всех краев каждого элемента внутри items__row, а ещё добавив flex-wrap в будущем чтобы при уменьшений экрана все начало друг под друга вставать, это не сработает ведь items__row будет увеличиваться в ширине бесконца, в итоге выходит за грани экрана и создавать белые пространства вокруг страницы. Если хочешь использовать gap, то сделай display:grid;

Comment: Какой-то фантастики написали. >также добавив просто gap: , ты сделаешь отступы со всех краев каждого элемента внутри items__row... `gap` добавляет отступы только между `flex` блоками. У крайних блоков отступы по краям будут отсутствовать. Если вы в превью кода увидели отступы и решили, что это `gap` их дорисовал, то ошиблись, это `padding: 0 45px;` их добавляет.

Answer (score 0):

я бы удалил класс `items__row` и применил его стили к `header__items`, вместе с `width: 100%;`

```css
* {
  color: black;
}

.header__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__items {
  opacity: 0.69;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__row">
  <div class="header__img">
    <img src="img/logo/logo_43.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="header__items">
    <div class="items__features">Features</div>
    <div class="items__about">About</div>
    <div class="items__pricing">Pricing</div>
    <div class="items__reviews">Reviews</div>
    <div class="items__contact">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

надеюсь помог